# Nginx POST subrequest changes character encoding

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use NJS code in Nginx to get a token from an Auth0 endpoint. The response body I get back is very strange, here is a sample:
d���N׎�}>��7���*j�8$A�$�"�����)�

The response code is a 200. Does anyone have any idea what's happening here?
Here is the sample code:

```
async function introspectAccessToken(r) {

    let res = await r.subrequest('/auth0/generate-token',
        { method:'POST', body: r.headersIn['auth-body']});

    r.log(res.responseText);

    if (res.status >= 300) {
        r.return(res.status, res.responseText);
        return;
    }

    r.return(200);
```

This line of code just retrieves the client id, secret etc from a header in the resquest and passes it in the request body to auth0:
body: r.headersIn['auth-body']});

Here is the nginx config snippet

```
location /auth0/generate-token {
                            resolver              1.1.1.1 ipv6=off;
                            set $empty "";
                                proxy_method      POST;
                                proxy_set_header accept "application/json";
                                proxy_set_header Content-Type "application/json";
            proxy_pass https://myauth0url
```

Any ideas?

Tried googling the issue, I've used a sample from stackoverflow that was similar but they actually get a proper result

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by removing the accept-encoding header in my request. It was set to gzip, deflate, br
Not entirely sure how this fixed it. My assumption is that the response was gzip and removing this forces it to use json

Comment: Please try to provide more details how you've fixed the issue. It might be useful to test the server e.g. with `curl -vL -H 'Accept: application/json' http://localhost`, where you can test the responses with different headers.